# Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in description

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 I have the following code in **description.phtml** for product view.

Where can I find/change that in Magento2? I cant find the file!!

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), nl2br($_description), 'description') ?>
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: No, because I have never got a working answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but on of the following should do the trick:

In your `phtml`-file (assuming your `$block` has a `getProduct()`-method):

```
<!-- old skool: -->
<?= nl2br($block->getProduct()->getDescription()) ?>
<?= nl2br($block->getProduct()->getData('description')) ?>
<!-- product interface compliant: -->
<?= nl2br($block->getProduct()->getCustomAttribute('description')->getValue()) ?>
```

Note that the above return the raw value of your attribute. In many cases you might want to apply filters to the content so that variables and widgets etc. get rendered properly. To do this you need to include the 
`\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider` as a dependency to your block class and utilize it:

Something like this should go in your block class to provide the functionality to your `phtml`-file:

```
public function getFilteredContent(ProductInterface $product)
{
    return $this->filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter(
        $product->getCustomAttribute('description')->getValue()
    );
}
```

Comment: In whitch file i can make the product interface compliant changes? I cant find the right file

Comment: I've added 2 extra notes to my answers to indicate where to put the lines.

Comment: Hello Giel, i use magento Luma, but i cant find the file to change. Can you help me? (Maarten from Nuenen)

Comment: Hello Maarten from Nuenen, I suggest you read the documentation on Magento 2 templating for this one: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-overview.html

Comment: ;-) 
I have read this, otherwise I would not ask a question here. I have created my own template and all adjustments work, except for the description. I have placed a file in it. design->frontend->mycompany->mytemplate->Magento_Catalog->templates->product->view->description.phtml but no result.

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the content of your `description.phtml`?

Comment: I believe that is because the `description.phtml`-template is not used in your case. If you look at `Mage_Catalog::catalog_product_view.xml` you see a section where the description is added as a tab on the product detail page. This effectively means that it uses the more generic `attribute.phtml` to render the description. So you need to do your changes there (I would suggest assigning a different `phtml` for description). Why there is a `description.phtml` in the first place? Don't know. Might be legacy, might be to not break BC. Welcome to Magento! ;-)